# On most modern 64-bit processors, does the speed of `mulq` depend on the operands?

Tags: performance, assembly, x86-64, cpu, intel

On most moder 64-bit processors (such as Intel Core 2 Duo or the Intel i7 series), does the speed of the x86_64 command `mulq` and its variants depend on the operands? For example, will multiplying `11 * 13` be faster than `11111111 * 13131313`? Or does it always take the time of the worst case?

Comment: Its speed does not depend on the values of the operands.

Comment: if it were floating point multiplication, I would say denormals as operands might slow it down, but since this is integer multiplication, this does not apply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have any reference to hand, but I would place money on the latency/throughput being invariant of the values of the operands.  Otherwise, it would be a nightmare to schedule.

Comment: Nightmare might be a bit strong.  There are all sorts of operations in a CPU with variable latency (loads, integer divide, many floating point operations, various CISCy type instructions).  The main reason that it is fixed latency is because it is so important that they put the transistors into it to make it fast (like 3 cycles).  The vast majority of operands would take 3 cycles and since it would be expensive and difficult to predict operands that would take 2 cycles or 1 it's not worth it given the penalty for mispredicting the hazard. It is also easy to hide a 3 cycle latency.

Answer (score 6):

**TL;DR: No. Constant-length integer math operations (barring division, which is non-linear) consume a constant number of cycles, regardless of the numerical value of the operands.**

`mulq` takes two QWORD arguments.

The values are represented in little-endian binary format (used by x86 architecture) as follows:

```
1011000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 =       13
1000110001111010000100110000000000000000000000000000000000000000 = 13131313
```

The processor sees both of these as the same "size", as both are 64-bit values.

Therefore, the cycle count should always be the same, regardless of the actual numerical value of the operands.

**More info:**

There are the concepts of *Leading Zero Anticipation* and *Leading Zero Detection*<sup>[[1](http://www.fdi.ucm.es/profesor/mozos/AEC/lza.pdf)][[2](http://www.research.ibm.com/arl/publications/papers/arithlza.PDF)]</sup> (LZA/LZD) that can be employed to speed up floating-point operations.

To the best of my knowledge however, there are no mainstream processors that employ either of these methods towards integer arithmetic. This is most likely due to the simplistic nature of most integer arithmetic (multiplication in this case). The overhead of LZA/LZD may simply not be worth it, for simple integer math circuits that can complete the full multiplication in less time anyhow.

Comment: Yeah but I heard that there are processors that can tell if the multiplication finished early (like if the rest of the bits are `0`s).

Comment: @Matt - You may be referring to LZA/LZD as described in http://www.research.ibm.com/arl/publications/papers/arithlza.PDF or http://www.fdi.ucm.es/profesor/mozos/AEC/lza.pdf AFAIK, no such equivalent exists in mainstream processors for integer mathematics.

Comment: @Matt - "AFAIK, no such equivalent exists in mainstream processors for integer mathematics." I have edited my answer as well.

Comment: Which actually has value dependent runtime even on modern processors.

Comment: @harol, drhirsch - You are quite right, I neglected to mention division, which is not generally a simple linear operation.

Comment: CPU architects wouldn't want a variable-latency multiplier for a modern CPU design like Sandybridge-family, for scheduling reasons.  The multiply unit is fully pipelined, starting one multiply per clock cycle.  If one finished early, in 2 cycles instead of 3, it could create a write-back conflict with a multiply started before this one: they'd both finish in the same cycle.  This is why Sandybridge-family doesn't have any 2-cycle-latency uops, only 1, 3, and 5, even though that means 3-component LEA is slower than it needs to be.

Comment: Also, it's very useful for the HW uop scheduler to know when the result will be ready so it can set up bypass forwarding and dispatch other uops waiting for that result so they'll already be hitting the execution units in the same cycle the result in produced and forwarded.  I assume this takes an extra cycle for division.  For loads, the scheduler is optimistic and does in practice have to replay dependent uops if the data didn't arrive from L1d cache when expected.  https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/48426964#48426964

Answer (score 2):

For decades, Agner Fog has been publishing [tables of instruction timings](https://www.agner.org/optimize/instruction_tables.pdf).  His August 2019 tables confirm what I had expected: that the CPU chips in modern laptops and desktop computers have invariant timing for their integer-multiply units.   These are extremely fast and rather power-hungry.

The CPU design space is quite different for battery-limited devices such as smartphones. On such devices, the integer multiply may be implemented in a microcoded loop with variable timing.

In (approx) 2016, Thomas Pornin had this to say about "the problem" posed by variable-latency multiplication instructions to the design of his SSL/TLS library:

"... integer multiplication opcodes in CPU may or may not execute in constant time; when they do not, implementations that use such operations may exhibit execution time variations that depend on the involved data, thereby potentially leaking secret information... When a CPU has non-constant-time multiplication opcodes, the execution time depends on the size (as integers) of one or both of the operands. For instance, on the ARM Cortex-M3, the umull opcode takes 3 to 5 cycles to complete, the `short' counts (3 or 4) being taken only if both operands are numerically less than 65536 ... In general, Intel x86 CPU all provide constant-time multiplications since the days of the first Pentium. The same does not necessarily hold for other vendors, in particular the early VIA Nano." [2](https://www.bearssl.org/ctmul.html)